# Django Admin adding dynamic list and delete action

Tags: django, django-admin

I have 2 models, Car and Driver:

```
class Driver(models.Model):
   name = models.TextField(max_length=50)
   diverText = models.TextField(max_length=300)
   car = models.ForeignKey(Car, default="", null=True, blank=True)

class Car(models.Model):
   name = models.TextField(max_length=300)
   model = models.TextField(max_length=300)
```

In my Django admin I have added an action, which shows me a list of all cars in the drop-down, which allows me to bulk assign drivers to a specific vehicle:

```
def create_action(car):
   def action(modeladmin, request, queryset): queryset.update(car=car)
   name = "mark_%s" % (car.name,)
   return name, (action, name,format(car.name +" "+ car.model ,))

class DriverAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   list_display = ('driver_name', 'driverText',  'car')

   def get_actions(self, request):
      return dict(create_action(q) for q in Car.objects.all())

   def driver_name(self, instance):
      return instance.driver.name

admin.site.register(Driver, DriverAdmin)
```

**Problem**:
I want to be able to delete one or more drivers in the admin, but when I add the above action the default delete option disappears from the select box. If a add a delete action in the overwritten method, the assign action disappears again. I´ve tried several ways to add it, but without luck. How do I keep both methods?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
def get_actions(self, request):
    actions = super(DriverAdmin, self).get_actions(request)
    return actions, dict(create_action(q) for q in Car.objects.all())
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I get the following error:

Traceback:
 
...action_form.fields['action'].choices = self.get_action_choices(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in get_action_choices
  897.         for func, name, description in six.itervalues(self.get_actions(request)):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/six.py" in itervalues
  573.         return iter(d.itervalues(**kw))

Exception Type: AttributeError at /admin/Core/driver/
Exception Value: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'itervalues'